# Запись структур в файл

Tags: c, структуры, файлы

Здравствуйте, программа пишет в файл структуру, после чего перестаёт работать. Написана на С, QNX Momentics IDE. Ниже приведён фрагмент кода. Если это не отнимет много времени, помогите, пожалуйста разобраться.

```
int i= 0;
printf("Enter name of file: ");
gets(fname);
fp = fopen(strcat(name1, fname),"w+");
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    pointer[i] = ftell(fp);
        puts("Enter name of student: ");
        gets(students[i].name);
    puts("Enter number of student's card: ");
    scanf("%u",students[i].kard);
    fwrite(students, sizeof(struct student), N, fp);
}
```

Comment: извините за небрежное оформление, нет времени

Comment: Вы бы написали определения всех массивов, всех структур, а то ничего непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное это (& перед students добавьте !!!!). Точнее по данному фрагменту кода сказать не могу.

```
scanf("%u",&students[i].kard);
fwrite(&students, sizeof(struct student), N, fp);
```

Comment: скорее всего, именно так, но без полного текста ничего непонятно.

Comment: В scanf, да, нужен &. А в fwrite как я понимаю сохраняется весь массив students, так что & не нужно.

Comment: А вот чего я **действительно не понимаю**, так это ***куда пропадают комментарии***.

Только что (когда набирал ответ) под вопросом был комментарий @Котик... , выделенный болдом. И вот, исчез.

Comment: не понятно только зачем каждый раз сохраняется весь массив. По замыслу наверное должно быть fwrite(students+i, sizeof(struct student), 1, fp);

Comment: @insolor, Cогласен, не вчитался.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую